# How do I output powershell foreach loop result into a text file?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, ansible, format

How do I output foreach loop result into a text file? I have a list of Active Directory names that I want to output into a text file in a table format, but only the first name is shown:

```
Name   SamAccountName UserPrincipalName        
----   -------------- -----------         
Greg   Gre.b87        Greg.b87@fs.com
```

This is my current code:

```
  - name: Run script
    ansible.windows.win_powershell: 
      script: |     
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [array]
            $namelist
        )

        foreach ($name in $namelist) {
             $results = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$name'" -Properties whenCreated | Select Name,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName
             echo "User Creation Successful:" 
             echo "$results"
             $results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\AD.txt -Width 5000 
        }

      parameters:
        namelist: "{{ hostvars.localhost.name_list[1:] }}"
```

**Update:**
Tried Dilly B's solution, and I got this:

```
Name   SamAccountName   whenCreated        
----   --------------   -----------        
Greg   Gre.b87          2/5/2023 8:12:47 AM
User Creation Successful: Gre.b87
Zee    zeef.cd          2/5/2023 8:12:53 AM
User Creation Successful: zeef.cd
Dawn   Dawn.5y          2/5/2023 8:13:00 AM
User Creation Successful: Dawn.5y
```

All the names are looped into the table now, but how should I write the code if I want the table to look like this?:

```
User creation successful:
Name   SamAccountName   whenCreated        
----   --------------   -----------        
Greg   Gre.b87          2/5/2023 8:12:47 AM
Zee    zeef.cd          2/5/2023 8:12:53 AM
Dawn   Dawn.5y          2/5/2023 8:13:00 AM
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to `$results | Export-Csv path.csv -NoTypeInformation` ?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this instead of   $results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\AD.txt -Width 5000 , and I still got the exact same output as Dilly B's solution

Comment: Thats fine, good luck importing that data back into something usable later

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now, one outputs the data in a csv format, the other is just purely a text file.

Comment: Correct. One can be imported back into objects very easily the other will require parsing

Answer (score 2):

you can collect results like this

```
$results = foreach ($name in $namelist) {
           Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$name'" -Properties whenCreated | Select Name,SamAccountName,UserPrincipalName
         Write-Host "User Creation Successful:$($name)"     
        }
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath C:\AD.txt -Width 5000
```

Comment: Thanks @Dilly B. I updated my question with the output from your solution. I want to ask, how do I write the code so that "User Creation Successful: " only appears once at the beginning of the output? I have listed an example of how the solution would look like.

Comment: Also, why did you use Write-Host instead of Write-Output? Is there some underlying difference? Because I see that the output is still the same.

Comment: The write-Host is for displaying results on-screen and Write-output for writing your results to a file. you have used echo, so I modified it as Write-Host. It is better to format the output as @Santiago Squarzon suggested. Incase if you want to have successful or unsuccessful on another column it is best to have try catch block.